# Nginx Static Content 404 Error on Every File Except Index

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have nginx 1.4.6 running  on an ubuntu 16.04 server.  My content consists of two files in the folder `/var/www/html/`, `index.html` and `test.html`.  All files are chmod'ed to 755 and belong to the user `www-data`.  My nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;                                                                                                                                  
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;


        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;                                                          
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";                                                                                                                                                    

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My configuration file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:

```
server {
      listen 80;

      root /var/www/html/;
      index index.html index.htm;

      server_name example.com;

      location / {

      }
}
```

When I browse to http://example.com/ (not the real hostname), I see the contents of `index.html` (yay).  When I browse to http://example.com/test.html I get HTTP 404.  I get this when I try to use curl, and any browser.

A lot of the other questions on this site (and on serverfault) seem to indicate problems serving static content with rewrite rules or a combination with reverse proxying to other services.  I just want to be able to serve the most simple static site imaginable.

Both the access.log and error.log do not even show that any requests are coming through.   The log files are both owned by and allow write access by user www-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current configuration on accessing `example.com` the control will be
 going to `location /` block there you have no entry point mentioned, hence
change the configuration to

```
server {
      listen 80;

      root /var/www/html/;
      index index.html index.htm;

      server_name example.com;

}
```

or

```
server {
      listen 80;    
      index index.html index.htm;    
      server_name example.com;

      location /{
        # you can use alias instead
        root /var/www/html/;
      }

}
```

Comment: What you posted works, but from what I can tell, is in direct contradiction with the Nginx documentation here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/ in the section "Root Inside Location Block" which is considered "bad".  The Nginx specified recommendation is what I adopted, which apparently is incorrect.  I am admittedly on an old version of Nginx, but whoever else finds this and tries to construct a simple example based directly off the docs: don't do it.

Comment: Actually, this appears to still not work.  I intermittently get 404 now, sometimes I get the correct page, other times I get 404.

Comment: @mephicide you can use alias instead... that means 
 `/` represents `html` folder